# Rails Layout Rendering with controller condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, conditional-statements

I don't know what's the best way to doing this.

On my application.html.erb I define a header div.

My default controller ( root ) is a homepage controller. 
And I wish that if I'm at index of the homepage the header is rendering with some content, but all other controllers render another content inside that header.

How can I make a condition in that header div to render different content based on the controller that's being rendered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#M001763) helper to define a block of markup in individual view templates that's yielded to from the application layout.

**application.html.erb**:

```
<div id="header">
  <%= yield :header %>
</div>
```

Then include code like this anywhere within a controller's view template:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  This is a controller-specific header.
<% end %>
```

Note that you can define as many of these blocks as you like, so you could have a conditional sidebar etc. as well.

- [Layouts and content_for Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for)